# Get Date time differnce base result (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I have a **deliverables** table and i want to get results where difference between current date time is 2 days from created date.

e.g today is 4-19-2017 i want to get all records where deadline is 4-21-2017 because here is difference of 2 days between 4-19-2017 and 4-21-2017  or also if 4-20-2017 it should also retrieve how ever if difference is more than 2 it should not be retrieve.

**In short if Difference between current date and deadline is 2 days or less should be retrieve**

I tried as

```
$deliverables_dead = DB::table('deliverables')->where('user_id' , Auth::user()->id)->where('deadline' , '>' , Carbon\Carbon::now())->get();
```

its get all records where is deadline greater than current time.

Please help how can i get answer of above bold statement......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `whereBetween()` and Carbon's `addDays()`:

```
DB::table('deliverables')
    ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
    ->whereBetween('deadline' , [Carbon\Carbon::now(), Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(2)])
    ->get();
```

Comment: dear sir can you update please that i will be able to know difference is one day or 2 days?

Comment: @bluemoon you mean you want to get two results - 0-24 hours from now and 24-48 hours from now? In this case, I'd recommend you to use Eloquent to load the data with the query above and then use collection helpers to filter results.

Comment: i just want to get difference in blade however i am able to get it in controller as `$date =  Carbon\Carbon::parse($deliverables_dead->deadline);
            $now = Carbon\Carbon::now();
            $length = $date->diffInDays($now);
            dd($length);`

how can i do same in blade?

Comment: Use Eloquent and add `deadline` to the `$dates` property. Then Laravel will automatically transform deadline date to the Carbon instance. You'll be able to do something like this in Blade then: `{{ $deliverable->deadline->diffInDays(Carbon::now()) }}`